# SQL - new column with the same cell value in every row for the same id without subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery

Sorry for bad title, I don't know how do describe better if you have a better one please tell me ;)

Please look at these small sql fiddle:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8f522/4/1

I need the "Value" from a specific "Title" in a new column ("Age"). But I need the "Value" in any row for the same "SN_Main".
The first query was my first try. It is fast and ok but I get the "Value" only for the row with the same "Title".

The second query is wat I want but the subquery is to slow, so I wanna solve this without subquery. The productive tables are bigger and I need this like 10 times and with subquery it become incredible slow.

So is there any way to get this output with other sql statements???

I hope you understand me, I'm so sorry about bad explanation :)

Regards
Martin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can join back onto the same table

```
SELECT MAIN.SN_Main
,MAIN.Data
,DETA.SN_Deta
,DETA.Title
,DETA.Value
,DETA2.Value AS Age
FROM MainData AS MAIN 
INNER JOIN DetaData AS DETA 
  ON MAIN.SN_Main = DETA.SN_Main
INNER JOIN DetaData as DETA2
  ON DETA.SN_Main = DETA2.SN_Main
  and DETA2.Title = 'Age'
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the second query like this. Use `Left Outer Join` instead of `correlated sub-query`

```
SELECT MAIN.SN_Main,
       MAIN.Data,
       DETA.SN_Deta,
       DETA.Title,
       DETA.Value,
       DETA2.Value AS Age
FROM   MainData AS MAIN
       INNER JOIN DetaData AS DETA
               ON MAIN.SN_Main = DETA.SN_Main
       LEFT JOIN DetaData AS DETA2
              ON DETA.SN_Main = DETA2.SN_Main
                 AND DETA2.Title = 'Age'
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?:

```
SELECT  m.[SN_Main]
    , m.[Data]
    , d.[SN_Deta]
    , d.[Title]
    , d.[Value]
    , da.[Value]
FROM    MainData m
INNER   JOIN    DetaData d
    ON  d.[SN_Main] = m.[SN_Main]
INNER   JOIN    DetaData da
    ON  da.[SN_Main] = m.[SN_Main]
    AND da.[Title] = 'Age'
```

Answer (score 0):

A proper index could also work :

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX idx_DetaData_SN_Main_Title ON DetaData
( SN_Main, Title) INCLUDE (Value)
```

And rewrite your query with inner join:

```
SELECT MAIN.SN_Main, MAIN.Data, DETA.SN_Deta, DETA.Title, DETA.Value, DETA2.Value
FROM MainData AS MAIN 
INNER JOIN DetaData AS DETA ON MAIN.SN_Main = DETA.SN_Main
INNER JOIN DetaData AS DETA2 ON MAIN.SN_Main = DETA2.SN_Main AND DETA2.Title = 'Age'
```

[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b9ce46/1)

Answer (score 0):

I would say that instead of not using a subquery, rather use it in a different way:

```
select main.*,
       age_lookup.age
  from detadata as main,       
       (select sn_main, 
               deta2.value as age
          from DetaData as deta2
         where title = 'Age') age_lookup
 where main.sn_main = age_lookup.sn_main;
```

With your subquery it will execute for each row, with the one above it will execute only once but use the results for every row.

Give it a try and let me know if the performance is okay.